# preimage of singular locus in resolution of singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety over a field of characteristic zero (say $\mathbb{C}$).
We say $X'$ is a resolution of singularities of $X$ if $X'$ is a smooth variety and there a birational and proper map $\pi$ from $X'$ to $X$. 
I am curious about whether the preimage of singular locus $\pi^{-1}(X_{sing})$ is of codim $1$ or not.

I am aware of Hironaka's method which always has the properties that $\pi^{-1}(X_{sing})$ is simple normal crossing divisor.

However, I don't know how the set $\pi^{-1}(X_{sing})$ looks like for general resolution of singularities. Does anyone can tell me whether $\pi^{-1}(X_{sing})$ is of codim $1$ or not?

If it is of codim $1$, can you provide an example when one of its irreducible component is singular?

If it is not , can you provide an example when it fails?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Preimage of singular locus would look like two overlapping/distinct points.

Comment: Please look up 'small resolution' to see examples where the exceptional locus is not of codimension one.